# ¿Como Enviar texto desde html a una dirección de correo?

Tags: javascript, html

estoy haciendo una página web y una parte tiene que ser enviar un formulario a una dirección de correo y no sé cómo hacerlo. Lo que ya tengo en el html es:

```
                <textarea name="mensaje" style="width:50%">
                </textarea>

            <input id="miboton" type="button" value="Enviar formulario" onclick="enviarFormulario()">
            </input>
```

Y en el javascript tengo:

```
function enviarFormulario(){
    alert("Formulario enviado correctamente");
}
```

Que de esta forma te muestra un campo de texto y luego un boton para enviarlo, aunque de momento sólo sale un mensaje.
Me podéis iluminar? Graciasss

Comment: Recuerda revisar las politicas de como preguntar para tus futuras preguntas. Redacta el titulo como una ´pregunta para empezar amigo :D

Answer (score 2):

Si usas por ejemplo la librería PHPMailer, para PHP puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('ejemplo@mail.com', 'Tu nombre');
$mail->addAddress('amigo@mail.com', 'Mi contacto');
$mail->Subject = 'Cuando te vuelva a ver';
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = 'Hola <h1>Saludos amigo que estes bien</h1>';
```

Como puedes notar en la última línea de código ya estoy en condiciones de usar código HTML y añandirle texto

> Esta librería para que funcione debes descargarla, los archivos donde uses esta lógica deben tener extensión .php; siempre manejar los datos sensibles de configuración del email es tenerlos del lado del servidor

Es decir necesitaras un lenguaje que pueda o tenga capacidad de procesar peticiones de correos, te dejo ese breve ejemplo pero si es necesario la descargues y adaptes a tus necesidades

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes:

Javascript no tiene utilidades para enviar e-mails.

Si tienes código por parte del servidor, puedes enviar el e-mail desde ahí, dependiendo del lenguaje que estés usando.

Si lo estás haciendo todo en el cliente desde Javascript, tienes dos formas:

- Usar el cliente de correo que tenga instalado el usuario que está
  usando el navegador:

  ```
    window.open('mailto:test@ejemplo.com?subject=subject&body=body');
  ```
- Debes importar una librería que añada esta funcionalidad a javascript, por ejemplo: [smtpJS](https://smtpjs.com/). Si usas GMAIL, tienen una API para JS que quizás te sirva de ayuda [en este enlace](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js).

Un saludo.

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero le falta advertir que A) `mailto:` solo abrirá el cliente de correo y dejará el e-mail "preparado", pero el usuario tendrá que darle a "Enviar" B) en estos días de correo web, puede ser que el navegador no sea capaz de preparar la página y C) si se usa SMTP desde el cliente, es muy probable que el antivirus/firewall bloquee la conexión. En general, solo recomendaría e-mails desde cliente si se trata de redes corporativas donde puedes controlar el SW de los clientes y la configuración de antivirus/firewalls/etc.

Comment: D) Con smtpJS o similar tendrás que poner la configuración de la cuenta de e-mail (usuario/contraseña/servidor) en el código del cliente, al alcance de cualquiera que lo quiera consultar.

Comment: Gracias @SJuan76 por las aclaraciones. Si bien sólo le quería dar opciones, realmente pienso que debería implementar tal funcionalidad en el lado del servidor (por los problemas que has comentado), pero no nos ha ofrecido información sobre si posee código en esa parte o en qué lenguaje :)

Comment: A ver, estoy de acuerdo que ésta es la respuesta que más se ajusta a lo que pide el OP, pero es que si no le añades las advertencias para mí se queda a medias.